# Agama prescribes that the dead bodies of Sannyasis should be buried. Then, why are the dead bodies of monks of the Ramakrishna Mission cremated?

Tags: rituals, tantra, death, agamas, ramakrishna

Mahanirbana Tantra categorically says that

> The corpse of an ascetic should on no account be cremated. It should be worshipped with scents and flowers, and then either buried or sunk into water. - Mahanirvana Tantra 8.284

Mahanirbana Tantra is one the 64 principal Shakta Tantras (List from Sarvollasa Tantra of Sarvanandanatha). So, this is the Agamic practice of the Shaktas. I know very well that Shakta Tantrik's bodies do get buried after death.

Even, I have even seen videos, where corpses of Gaudiya Vaishnava saints get buried. Though, Vaishnavas do not follow Shakta Tantras, however, they do follow Pancharatra Agamas. So, it is clear that this practice is not specific to Shaktas, rather this is a general Agamic practice.

However, the corpse of the monks of the Ramakrishna mission gets cremated. Swami Vivekananda's body was also cremated in Belur Math.

My question is why Ramakrishna Mission does not follow this practice? Based on what scripture they cremate the dead bodies of saints?

Reference -

[Mahanirvana Tantra translated by Arthur Avalon](https://www.globalgreyebooks.com/mahanirvana-tantra-ebook.html)

Comment: Many sannyasins are burned. It is not only Ramakrishna Mission sadhus.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Cite the scriptural reference in support of this practice. That is far better option than giving a negative vote, I guess.

Comment: "Many sannyasins are burned." -- that does not make it right .. as Sannyasis are not supposed to be burned as per various scriptures @SwamiVishwananda show me one scripture which supports cremation of Sannyasis